# How to Extend login session times to a Month

Tags: functions, id, session

How can I extend wordpress login sessions to a month so that it doesn’t automatically ask for login after 48 hours?

I am basically testing some program with wordpress and around 48 hours it fails and I’m pretty sure it has to do with the session id... So please help me extend it to at least a month!

Comment: As a side-note, it would be helpful to ask about the original problem, there's no guarantee that this will fix it, or that your theory is correct. E.g. if the problem is REST API sessions timing out, there are other/better solutions unrelated to logging session time periods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the login cookie lasts for

- 14 days if you tick 'remember me'
- 48 hours if you don't

So as a short term fix you probably want to tick 'remember me', and to extend that to 30 days you can add an [auth_cookie_expiration](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_cookie_expiration/) filter e.g.

```php
function auth_cookie_expiration_30_days( $seconds, $user_id, $remember_me ) {
    if ( $remember_me ) {
        return 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS;
    }
    
    return $seconds;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'auth_cookie_expiration_30_days', 10, 3 );
```

As you can see you can set per-user-ID durations and you can change the don't-remember-me time here too if you want, although above I'm leaving that as the default.

Comment: Thanks for your Help. Should I paste the code as a whole in my function.php(Inside Theme editor)? Or I need to change something?

Comment: Also, if I change 30 to 90, will that be 3 months?

Comment: if 90 days is 3 months then yes, it will be 3 months. The hook goes anywhere a hook would go

Comment: Well well, I can't thank you enough :)
Thanks Man :)